# TikZ grid - filling a cell by directly accsessing it

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I discovered TikZ the day before yesterday and now I try to create a grid with 10 columns and 10 rows. It would be convenient to fill the grid boxes with color in a constant and clear manner. I hope to do this from outside of the grid matrix.

I am able to name the matrix with (M). In the user manual of pgf I can only find one instance where the naming command is used.

In the picture below you can see a horizontal black line which resulted from directly accessing two nodes.

How could I use the command 'fill' instead of 'draw', in order to fill one cell in a clear manner?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw,minimum size=1cm}, nodes in empty cells,column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth](M){
 |[fill=green]|  &  |[fill=red]|     & |[fill=blue]| & |[fill=purple]|  \\
 |[fill=yellow]| &  |[fill=orange]|  & |[fill=green]| & |[fill=brown]|  \\
      };

\draw[black] (M-1-1) -- (M-1-3) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! If I correctly understood you, than you afer the following:

[image]

**Edit:**

What embarrassing, My previous explanation was wrong, so I delete it and recover last example from first solution . Yo have correct setting of matrix ...

In the first attempt I overlooked the problems with drawing cells' borders. Concerning it, use of rectangle cover borders. So visually correct result you get only if rectangle fill is black`(as are cells' borders), at other fill colors, borders of colored cells are covered by`fill`. This can be avoided by use` fit` library and painting cells only inside borders:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, 
             nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm}, 
             nodes in empty cells,
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth, % <---
             row sep=-\pgflinewidth]    % <---
{
    &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   \\
};

\node[fill, inner sep=-\pgflinewidthpt, fit=(m-2-3)] {}; % <---
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm},
             nodes in empty cells,
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth,  % <---
             row sep=-\pgflinewidth]     % <---
{
    &   &               &   \\
    &   & |[fill=teal]| &   \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for being not clear enough. For example, I want to exchange the color from green to black only in the left top field. \fill[black] (m-1-1) does not work in this scenario, does it?

Comment: No. See edit to my answer. There are two scenarios, one how you can paint cell outside of matrix and one, which people usually use, by defining option to this cell.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it thoroughly! Also for pointing out the common method. However, with 100 cells I feel lost in the options when they are written in the cells directly. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Thank you once again for providing the solution! I saw the overfill cell color in my editor, but thought that I would tackle this problem another time.

Comment: @17757970, interestingly, I have a completely opposite feeling, so I newer do on the way as you trying to do.  I rather put some effort to writing of code in editor, that its structure is similar to drawn matrix. BTW, see  edited answer. I change it completely (remove use of rectangle, because result is wrong,  point to errors in  your MWE at defining columns and rows separation).

Comment: @17757970, I'm very sorry but I edited my answer again and correct some my wrong statement in the explanation. Your MWE was and is just fine!

Comment: I created a [follow-up question] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628133/tikz-border-alignment-with-fit-library) as I do not understand it properly. Sorry.