# TikZ - border alignment with fit library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

This is a follow-up question to [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628122/260255).

On the picture below one can see the misalignment of the cells in comparison of using and not using fit library.

Which options should I give the fit library in order to properly align the borders of the cells, if my matrix options are supposedly fine.

Thank you once again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, 
                     nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm}, 
                     nodes in empty cells,
                     column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
                     row sep=-\pgflinewidth]
        {
            &   &   &   \\
            &   &   &   \\
        };
        
        \node[fill=orange, draw, inner sep=0pt, fit=(m-2-3)] {};
        \node[fill=blue, inner sep=0pt, fit=(m-1-1)] {};
        \node[fill=red, inner sep=0pt, fit=(m-2-1)] {};

    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, 
                     nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm}, 
                     nodes in empty cells,
                     column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
                     row sep=-\pgflinewidth]
        {
            |[fill=blue]|    &   &   &   \\
            |[fill=red]|    &   &  |[fill=orange]|  &   \\
        };
        
       
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Sorry, but you are victim of my answers changes. Now should be correct in the very first attempt:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{fill=#1, inner sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
                          fit=#2, node contents={} } % <--- new
                    ]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
                 nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm},
                 nodes in empty cells,
                 column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                 row sep=-\pgflinewidth]
    {
        &   &   &   \\
        &   &   &   \\
    };
    \node[FIT=orange/(m-2-3)]; % <--- changed
    \node[FIT=blue/(m-1-1)];
    \node[FIT=red/(m-2-1)];
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
                     nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm},
                     nodes in empty cells,
                     column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                     row sep=-\pgflinewidth]
        {
        |[fill=blue]|   &   &                   &   \\
        |[fill=red]|    &   & |[fill=orange]|   &   \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From comparison of your and mine MWE you can see, that esential difference is in defining `inner sep` in nodes. You are set it to zelo, I to `\pgflinewidth`.

For shorter code is in my MWE defined new style `FIT`, by which codes for matrix cells painting if shorter.

Comment: I am glad you helped me! I am not a victim at all, just a confused beginner. Thank you again.